# Why does the test fail and is it possible to use it alternatively?

Tags: python-3.x

In this case, checking for the presence of 0 in two variables and characters in the third variable worked.

```
first, second, operation = float(input()), float(input()), input()
if (second == 0 or first == 0) and (operation == "/" or operation == "div" or operation == "mod"):
    print("Division by 0!")
    exit(0)

Сomputation = {
    "+": first + second,
    "-": first - second,
    "*": first * second,
    "/": first / second,
    "mod": first % second,
    "pow": first ** second,
    "div": first // second
}

Status = False
for keys in Сomputation.keys():
    if operation == keys:
       Status = True
       print(Сomputation[keys])

if Status != True:
    print("Did not work")
```

Here, the same check, but after creating the dictionary does not work.

```
first, second, operation = float(input()), float(input()), input()

Сomputation = {
    "+": first + second,
    "-": first - second,
    "*": first * second,
    "/": first / second,
    "mod": first % second,
    "pow": first ** second,
    "div": first // second
}

Status = False
for keys in Сomputation.keys():
    if operation == keys:
       Status = True
       if (second == 0 or first == 0) and (operation == "/" or operation == "div" or operation == "mod"):
           print("Division by 0!")
       else:
           print(Сomputation[keys])

if Status != True:
    print("Do not work")
```

Comment: you forgot to post failing code

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary will immediately carry out the functions that is allocated to it. So the script will fail because the divide by 0 function will be evaluated when the dictionary is initialized. The first script works because the check for divide for 0 occurs before the dictionary is initialized. Please move the check to before the dictionary is initialized.

Comment: Or better yet, make the values of the dict functions that are only evaluated when needed.

Comment: yeap you can use lambdas or the `operator` module